PMD/Checkmarx did not flag SOQL Injection Vulnerability
The code below from the managed package queries data from Salesforce. The query is stored in a custom object called Config. Queries are stored in a custom object so that the admin can write custom queries as per their needs.
I think there is an SOQL injection vulnerability because the query is being fetched from a text field. We run into issues if the string is escaped using String.escapeSingleQuotes(query). This is because the query is already escaped before it is stored in the database.
public with sharing class DataFetcher {
  public static List<SObject> fetchData(Config__c config) {
    try {
      return Database.query(
        config.Query__c,
        AccessLevel.USER_MODE
      );
    } catch (Exception e) {
      System.debug('Exception occurred while fetching data from org' + e);
    }
    return null;
  }
}

Is this a SOQL injection vulnerability (provided that only admins will be able to edit the queries)? It's not flagged as a vulnerability by either of the code scanners, Checkmarx and SF Code Analyzer.
Will this be an issue for the manual security review of the package?
Should be include this as false negative for security review?

In terms of formal definition of an injection vulnerability, this is a borderline case. There isn't a threat vector where the end user (not admin) can influence the outcome of the query, at least not from the snippet you posted. The admins can mess with it, sure, but admins can do a lot of damage in many other ways.

You are right @identigral, I had the same thoughts, but I would like to know if anyone was able to pass the security review with code like this.

I would say this is a vulnerability and you need to do the escaping on use, not on storage of the query text.

But when its stored in the field, it is auto escaped internally by Salesforce, and that is creating double escape.
